# SQLite inserting Data is very slow, even with BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've got an *.sql script with 72.000 INSERT statements.
I put BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION statements every 10.000 lines.
So it kinda looks like this:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO Symbols (Market, Symbol, Description) VALUES ('AMEX','AAAU','Perth Mint Physical Gold ETF');
    ... 9.999 other INSERTs
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The C# code looks like this:

```
            var seedData = File.ReadAllText(sqlScriptFilePath);

            using (var db = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                db.Open();

                var sqlCmdInsert = new SqliteCommand(seedData, db);
                sqlCmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

                db.Close();
            }
```

It takes over 30min to finish inserting. What am I doing wrong? I thought splitting it into multiple transactions would help.

Comment: try chunking the insert into batches of 1000  - i have found that to be useful in the past...

Comment: also check if you can put the SqliteCommand into a `using` block like the connection

Comment: *Plenty* of good resources to the right under **Related**.  Everytime this comes up there is some dubious or naive practices which ends up being to blame.

Comment: You can load it to some temporary table and then insert to the Symbol table at once. You would find out if the problem is between client and server or in the inserting.